# When JQuery change function is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I am using Jquery to set some flag whenever `input` elements value get changed.

I wrote a simple script which is working fine but I observed that the function get called only when control get out of the `input` element.If user types something and keeps the control in the same `input` then function is not called.

I want to execute the function whenever `input` elements value get changed irrespective of where the control is.

Here is my code

```
$("input,textarea").live('change',function ()
{
   // Set flag
});
```

I am using `live()` to bind `change()` method to dynamicaly added `input` elements.

~ Ajinkya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyup/keydown event instead of change:

```
$("input,textarea").live('keyup',function ()
{
   // Set flag
});
```

Comment: Will it be applicable to `select` ?

Comment: @Ajinkya it's applicable to select if yopu choose values with keyboard. Usually i bind both keyup and change on selects

Comment: Will it make any impact on performance as two functions get called on same event ?

Comment: @Ajinkya i never noticed that. Moreover it's only when a select is changed using keyboard that the two events are fired (when you change it with the mouse the keyup event is not fired)

Comment: Ya.I check with `select` only. Its fine.So I will use `keyup` and `change`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, the `change` event is triggered when the element loses focus.  That's when its `value` property is updated.

If you want to work whenever a key is pressed, use the `keypress` event:

```
$("input,textarea").live('keypress',function ()
{
   // Set flag
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between `keyup` and `keypress` ?

Comment: usually it's told that keypress isn't consistent in browser. Is it still so or do you use this withouth problems?

Comment: @Ajinkya Yes, a couple. Have a look at the docs pages. Basically, `keypress` is the semantic version when you want to know about a visible character being entered. @Nicola For this case, yes it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The 'change' event works as lonesomeday said.
But if you want to set your flag whenever something occurs, you can create your own event.
For instance, with your custom event, you can set your flag if the user change the field, press a key, focus on the element or anything you want.

To know more about that: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/4/jquery-edge-new-special-event-hooks

Comment: I used `keyup` and `change`. It provides the desired outcome :) Thanks for the suggestion.